# How to create a filter with four input textures using GPUImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

I have a fragment shader code that requires four input textures like this:

```
 precision lowp float;

 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture4;

 void main()
  {

  vec4 texel = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
   vec3 bbTexel = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate).rgb;

   texel.r = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, vec2(bbTexel.r, texel.r)).r;
   texel.g = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, vec2(bbTexel.g, texel.g)).g;
   texel.b = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, vec2(bbTexel.b, texel.b)).b;

   vec4 mapped;
   mapped.r = texture2D(inputImageTexture4, vec2(texel.r, .16666)).r;
   mapped.g = texture2D(inputImageTexture4, vec2(texel.g, .5)).g;
   mapped.b = texture2D(inputImageTexture4, vec2(texel.b, .83333)).b;
   mapped.a = 1.0;

   gl_FragColor = mapped;
 }
```

and as the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) only provide [GPUImageThreeInputFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageThreeInputFilter.m) at most, how do I write a filter with four input texture ? I have read the [IFImageFilter](https://github.com/anbinh/Instagram-Filters/blob/master/InstaFilters/IFImage/IFImageFilter.m) which is available for more than 3 input textures (up to 6 input textures), but it can not be compiled with latest GPUImage.

Comment: You'll need to follow the template of GPUImageThreeInputFilter, and see how it adds that extra input to the GPUImageTwoInputFilter. Do what it does, only add another input to GPUImageThreeInputFilter instead.

Comment: @BradLarson I've wrote a similar filter class called GPUImageFourInputFilter, modified from GPUImageThreeInputFilter but it does not work well. link: https://gist.github.com/Moligaloo/53f5d988b376333552ff

Comment: Finally I got it working here. https://gist.github.com/johnpaulmanoza/7476140094a9cb9dd4c3